# Adding UMP SDK through ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

```
Beginning January 16, 2024, Google will require all publishers serving ads to EEA and 
UK users to use a Google-certified Consent Management Platform (CMP). 
You can use any Google-certified CMP for this purpose, including Google's own consent management solution. 
If you are interested in using 
Google's consent management solution, start by setting up your 
GDPR message and implementing the UMP SDK. Learn more
```

This is the message I am getting on admob page. All of my apps are built with ionic. Are there tutorials how to implement this sdk with ionic?

Comment: have you read this section:
https://github.com/capacitor-community/admob?tab=readme-ov-file#user-message-platform-ump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need android tutorials, which is provided by google in the 'learn more' section or in [here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/ump/android/quick-start).

after you've built your project into android, just open android studio with your android folder project (by either `npx cap open android` command, or manually opening android studio and open the android folder in your project). then you need to make the changes mentioned in the tutorial (if you want to go with the google's way and not other CMPs).

the only issue is that the `onCreate` function that you need to override is in capacitor bridge file in `node_modules` (which is located here:
`\node_modules\@capacitor\android\capacitor\src\main\java\com\getcapacitor\BridgeActivity.java`). you need to be careful that you might need to replace the file everytime your `node_modules` are recreated, before building apks. the better way would be to wait until someone writes a plugin for this (I didn't find any plugin yet) or write one yourself.
also I'd note that the `AndroidManifest.xml` is located in `android\app\src\main`
and the `build.gradle` file in documents is the one located in `android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins`